# Add additional behaviour to existing Eclipse button?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to add additional behaviour to an existing button in the Eclipse ide with a plugin. 
To have an example, I would like to print to standard out each time the "Remove Launch" button in the console view gets pressed (see image).[image]

Should I find and override/extend the corresponding, existing `Handler` with my logic?

Should I work with the these extensions?

```
ConsoleView extension locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView"

Commands extension: "org.eclipse.ui.commands"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a general way to hook in to existing actions.

For Remove Launch you can set up a listener to be notified of removed launches by using the `ILaunchManager`:

```java
ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();

launchManager.addLaunchListener(listener);
```

The listener is an `ILaunchesListener` which has a `launchesRemoved` method that will be called when a launch is removed.